R Shiny: Handling an "Error in .checkTypos"
I have a data.table with two columns: "Date" and "Col2". To use this data.table I have built a shiny app with the following two functionality. The first functionality does not allow to put in the "Date" column any type of string but only a date. The second functionality has to do with dateRangeInput().
When I run the shinyApp() containing only one of these functionalities, it works well. However, when I put both functionalities together into one code I am getting an Error in .checkTypos: text string does not conform to standard unambiguous format and the shiny app is getting crashed. This error is popping up when I write some text in the 'Date' column instead of choosing from the drop-down calendar or entering a date in a correct format manually.
I have tried many combinations and alterations but could not escape this error.
Can someone show me what I am missing or doing wrong with the code?
Below you find my code with both functionalties integrated.
 library(shiny)
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(rhandsontable)
 library(data.table)
 library(shinyalert)

 DF1 <- data.table(
             "Date" = as.character(NA),
             "Col2" = as.character(NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 DF2 <- data.table(
             "Date" = as.character(NA),
             "Col2" = as.character(NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 ui <- fluidPage(
   dashboardPage(
     dashboardHeader(title = NULL),
     dashboardSidebar(
       sidebarMenu(
         menuItem("reprex", tabName = "table1")
     )
   ),
   dashboardBody(
       tabItems(
         tabItem(tabName = "table1",
           fluidRow(
             column(
               width = 6,
               label = NULL,
               rHandsontableOutput("table1Item1")
             ),
             column(
               width = 6,
               "Choose btw Date and Col2",
               selectInput("choices", label=NULL,
                           choices = c("Filter by Date", "Filter by Col2")),
               uiOutput("nested_ui1")
             ),
             column(
               width = 6,
               label=NULL,
               rHandsontableOutput("table1Item2")
             )
           )
         )
       )
     )
   )
 )
 server = function(input, output, session) {

   data <- reactiveValues()

   observe({
     data$df1 <- as.data.table(DF1)
     data$df2 <- as.data.table(DF2)
   })

 observeEvent(input$table1Item1, {
   if (!is.null(input$table1Item1)) {
     data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1)

     if (any(is.character(as.Date(data$df1$`Date`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")))) {
        return()
     }
        data$df1$`Date` <- format(as.Date(data$df1$`Date`, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
     }
 })

 observe({
     if (!is.null(input$table1Item1) && !any(is.na(input$dates1))) {
             data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1) 

     if (!any(is.na(input$dates1)) && input$choices == "Filter by Date") {
         from=as.Date(input$dates1[1L])
         to=as.Date(input$dates1[2L])
         if (from>to) to = from
         selectdates1 <- seq.Date(from=from, to=to, by = "day")
         data$df2 <- data$df1[as.Date(data$df1$"Date") %in% selectdates1, ]
     } else if (!is.null(input$text) && input$choices == "Filter by Col2") {
         data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$"Col2" == input$text, ]
     } else {
         selectdates2 <- unique(data$df1$"Date")
         data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$"Date" %in% selectdates2, ]
     }
   }
 })  

   output$table1Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
     rhandsontable(data$df1, stretchH = "all", height = 300) |>
       hot_col(1, dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD", type = "date")
  })

   output$nested_ui1 <- renderUI({
     if (input$choices == "Filter by Date") {
         dateRangeInput("dates1", "Filter by Date:", format="yyyy-mm-dd",
                        start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), separator = "-")
   } else if (input$choices == "Filter by Col2") {
    textInput("text", "Filter by Col2:")
   }
 })

 output$table1Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
   rhandsontable(data$df2)
 })

 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)


A simple fix is setting allowInvalid = FALSE in your rhandsontable call:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(shinyalert)

DF1 <- data.table(
  "Date" = as.character(NA),
  "Col2" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF2 <- data.table(
  "Date" = as.character(NA),
  "Col2" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = NULL),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("reprex", tabName = "table1")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "table1",
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    label = NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    "Choose btw Date and Col2",
                    selectInput("choices", label=NULL,
                                choices = c("Filter by Date", "Filter by Col2")),
                    uiOutput("nested_ui1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    label=NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item2")
                  )
                )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    data$df1 <- as.data.table(DF1)
    data$df2 <- as.data.table(DF2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table1Item1, {
    if (!is.null(input$table1Item1)) {
      data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1)
      
      if (any(is.character(as.Date(data$df1$`Date`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")))) {
        return()
      }
      data$df1$`Date` <- format(as.Date(data$df1$`Date`, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1Item1) && !any(is.na(input$dates1))) {
      data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1) 
      
      if (!any(is.na(input$dates1)) && input$choices == "Filter by Date") {
        from=as.Date(input$dates1[1L])
        to=as.Date(input$dates1[2L])
        if (from>to) to = from
        selectdates1 <- seq.Date(from=from, to=to, by = "day")
        data$df2 <- data$df1[as.Date(data$df1$"Date") %in% selectdates1, ]
      } else if (!is.null(input$text) && input$choices == "Filter by Col2") {
        data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$"Col2" == input$text, ]
      } else {
        selectdates2 <- unique(data$df1$"Date")
        data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$"Date" %in% selectdates2, ]
      }
    }
  })  
  
  output$table1Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df1, stretchH = "all", height = 300, allowInvalid = FALSE) |>
      hot_col(1, dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD", type = "date")
  })
  
  output$nested_ui1 <- renderUI({
    if (input$choices == "Filter by Date") {
      dateRangeInput("dates1", "Filter by Date:", format="yyyy-mm-dd",
                     start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), separator = "-")
    } else if (input$choices == "Filter by Col2") {
      textInput("text", "Filter by Col2:")
    }
  })
  
  output$table1Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df2)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Another option would be using tryCatch when assigning the data to the reactiveValues:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(shinyalert)

DF1 <- data.table(
  "Date" = as.character(NA),
  "Col2" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF2 <- data.table(
  "Date" = as.character(NA),
  "Col2" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = NULL),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("reprex", tabName = "table1")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "table1",
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    label = NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    "Choose btw Date and Col2",
                    selectInput("choices", label=NULL,
                                choices = c("Filter by Date", "Filter by Col2")),
                    uiOutput("nested_ui1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    label=NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item2")
                  )
                )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    data$df1 <- as.data.table(DF1)
    data$df2 <- as.data.table(DF2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table1Item1, {
    if (!is.null(input$table1Item1)) {
      data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1)
      
      if (any(is.character(as.Date(data$df1$`Date`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")))) {
        return()
      }
      data$df1$`Date` <- format(as.Date(data$df1$`Date`, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1Item1) && !any(is.na(input$dates1))) {
      tryCatch({
        data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1) 
        if (!any(is.na(input$dates1)) && input$choices == "Filter by Date") {
          from=as.Date(input$dates1[1L])
          to=as.Date(input$dates1[2L])
          if (from>to) to = from
          selectdates1 <- seq.Date(from=from, to=to, by = "day")
          data$df2 <- data$df1[as.Date(data$df1$"Date") %in% selectdates1, ]
        } else if (!is.null(input$text) && input$choices == "Filter by Col2") {
          data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$"Col2" == input$text, ]
        } else {
          selectdates2 <- unique(data$df1$"Date")
          data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$"Date" %in% selectdates2, ]
        }
      },  error = function(e){print(e)})
    }
  })  
  
  output$table1Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df1, stretchH = "all", height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD", type = "date")
  })
  
  output$nested_ui1 <- renderUI({
    if (input$choices == "Filter by Date") {
      dateRangeInput("dates1", "Filter by Date:", format="yyyy-mm-dd",
                     start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), separator = "-")
    } else if (input$choices == "Filter by Col2") {
      textInput("text", "Filter by Col2:")
    }
  })
  
  output$table1Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df2)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Dear ismirsehregal, thanks for your efforts. It is a proper solution. It also would be beneficial for all learners if you can showcase another option with tryCatch() as well.

@firuz.safaev I added an example using tryCatch() to print the error instead of crashing the app. Of course this could be modified to what ever error handling you need.

dear @ismirsehregal, tryCatch() worked as well. Thanks a lot!
